# How should I deal with the running Apache IoTDB server when I need to copy storage groups to another IoTDB server?

Tags: copy, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to copy several storage groups from the running Apache IoTDB server to load into another IoTDB server. I want to know do I need to stop the current running IoTDB during the copy progress? Any files that I also need to copy or delete after copying storage groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to ensure data consistency between these two IoTDB servers? If data needs to be consistent, you have to stop writing, flush the system and then copy the storage group you want. If you don't need to guarantee consistency, you can directly copy the storage group, but you need to check and delete the tsfiles without `resource` file in Apache IoTDB. Otherwise, the `load` progress will report an error.